# java static binding and polymorphism

Tags: java, inheritance, binding, static, polymorphism

I am confused with the static binding example below. I reckon that `S2.x` and `S2.y` shows static binding as they prints out the fields according to `s2`'s static type. And `S2.foo()` makes `s2`call the `foo` method in the super class, as `foo` is not over ridden in the subclass.

However with `S2.goo()`, isn't it supposed to call the `goo()` method in the `Test1` subclass? Like it's polymorphism? How come it's static binding? It looks like `S2.goo()` calls the Super Class `goo()`method and prints out `=13`. Many thanks for your help in advance!

```
public class SuperClass {
  public int x = 10; 
  static int y = 10; 
protected SuperClass() { 
     x = y++; 
 } 
 public int foo() { 
     return x; 
 } 
 public static int goo() { 
     return y; 
 } 
}
```

and SubClass

```
public class Test1 extends SuperClass {
 static int x = 15;
 static int y = 15;
 int x2= 20; 
 static int y2 = 20; 

 Test1() 
 { 
     x2 = y2++; 
 } 
 public int foo2() { 
     return x2; 
 } 
 public static int goo2() { 
     return y2; 
 } 

public static int goo(){
     return y2;
 }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SuperClass s1 = new SuperClass();
    SuperClass s2 = new Test1();
    Test1 t1 = new Test1();

    System.out.println("S2.x = " + s2.x); 
    System.out.println("S2.y = " + s2.y); 
    System.out.println("S2.foo() = " + s2.foo()); 
    System.out.println("S2.goo() = " + s2.goo());
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java static variables and methods are not polymorphic. You can't expect polymorphic behavior with static fields.

Comment: to add to this calling s2.goo() is not a call done on object but on the class variable that s2 refers which is SuperClass. So effectively the superclass method is called irrespective of underlying object

Answer (score 1):

**Static methods can not be overridden, because they get bind with the class at compile time itself.**
**However, you can hide the static behavior of a class** like this:

```
public class Animal {
   public static void foo() {
    System.out.println("Animal");
   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Animal.foo(); // prints Animal
       Cat.foo(); // prints Cat
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
   public static void foo() {  // hides Animal.foo()
     System.out.println("Cat");
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Animal
Cat
```

Refer [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) for method hiding in Java.
Also, take care that static method should not be called on instance as they get bind to Class itself.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks! so the static method is called according to the static type of the variable? I mean in your example, if we create Animal monster = new Cat(), then monster.foo() will still prints out "animal"?